# How to redirect a user into the native camera app from JS/HTML?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I would like to add a button/link in JS/HTML that causes the user to leave the web browser and have their native camera app open.

I do not want to receive any images or video - I want the user to end up in their normal camera app where they can use it as if they were never on my website.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: It's a normal website or hybrid app (like cordova)?

Comment: there is no direct way to open the user's native camera app from a web browser without involving media capture or receiving images/videos in some form.

Comment: However, you can achieve a similar result by using the HTML
<input type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" capture>
Note that browser behavior may vary, and some browsers might ignore the capture attribute and display the file picker dialog instead.

Comment: It's a normal website for an event I'm organising. The hope was that users would be able to utilise the native camera QR code scanning which I imagine won't be enabled when using the file input.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that doesn't work.

I once wrote a small local web server in Python. You could then click on the links that ran the programs. It then worked in such a way that the command arrived in the web server (Python) and Python then executed it on the same device.